# Unable to mock a trait returning Option<&String>

Tags: rust

I am trying to mock a trait using the [`mockall`](https://docs.rs/mockall/0.8.3/mockall/) crate:

```rust
#[automock]
trait Foo {
  fn foo(input: &Vec<String>) -> Option<&String>;
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error[E0637]: `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here
  --> src/names_matcher.rs:79:51
   |
79 |             fn foo(input: &Vec<String>) -> Option<&String>;
   |                                                   ^ explicit lifetime name needed here

error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
  --> src/names_matcher.rs:77:9
   |
77 |         #[automock]
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         ...but data from `input` is returned here
78 |         trait Foo {
79 |             fn foo(input: &Vec<String>) -> Option<&String>;
   |                           ------------ this parameter and the return type are declared with different lifetimes...
```

The function I want to implement will return either None or Some with a reference to one of the elements of the vector in input. If I try to define the lifetimes taking this into account:

```rust
#[automock]
trait Foo {
  fn foo<'r>(input: &'r Vec<String>) -> Option<&'r String>;
}
```

I get the following:

```
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'r`
  --> src/names_matcher.rs:79:20
   |
79 |             fn foo<'r>(input: &'r Vec<String>) -> Option<&'r String>;
   |                    ^^ undeclared lifetime
   |
help: consider introducing lifetime `'r` here
   |
77 |         #[automock]<'r>
   |                    ^^^^
help: consider introducing lifetime `'r` here
   |
77 |         'r, #[automock]
   |         ^^^
```

But none of the suggestions work, they produce syntax errors. Is there a way to mock a trait like the one I defined above?

Comment: Can you attach the lifetime to `Foo`?

Comment: I tried as well, but it fails saying the lifetime is not defined

Comment: https://docs.rs/mockall/0.8.3/mockall/#generic-methods
"The only restrictions on mocking generic methods are that all generic parameters must be 'static, and generic lifetime parameters are not allowed." You will probably need to `mock!` it manually.